# generate unique possible combinations beased on items in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a panda dataframe that looks like:

```
dealerId | product | bid | supplier | cost
------------------------------------------
dealer1    product1  1.5    supplier1  1.4 
dealer1    product1  1.5    supplier2  1.1 
dealer1    product2  2.0    supplier3  1.3 
dealer1    product2  2.0    supplier4  1.6 
dealer2    product2  2.0    supplier4  1.6 
dealer2    product2  2.0    supplier4  1.6 
dealer2    product2  2.0    supplier4  1.6 
dealer3    ... ... ... ...
```

and so on. How can I get all possible unique combinations of cost based on dealer id and product? example of output

```
combination = {(1.4,1.3) (1.4,1.6) (1.1,1.3)...}
```

Comment: Show what you've done. SO is not a coding for free site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
from itertools import combinations
combinations = set(combinations(df['cost'].unique(),2))
```

If you are looking for combinations for each dealer and product,

```
df.groupby(['dealerId', 'product']).cost.apply(lambda x: set(combinations(x.unique(), 2)))
```